# How do I calculate the distance by taking rssi values from a text file?

Tags: python

This is my file.txt

```
Timestamp                    MAC                  RSSI

2021-04-30T14:41:13Z         AC233FA27B5C         -20
2021-04-30T14:41:14Z         AC233FA27B6A         -23
2021-04-30T14:41:14Z         AC233FA27B5B         -25
2021-04-30T14:41:15Z         AC233FA27B5C         -20
2021-04-30T14:41:14Z         AC233FA27B6A         -23
2021-04-30T14:41:15Z         AC233FA27B5B         -25
2021-04-30T14:41:45Z         AC233FA27B5C         -20
```

I want to read the rssi values from the text file called "test.txt" and insert them in a python script below

```
import math
txpower = -40   
ratio =(txpower-rssi)/40
distance= math.pow(10,ratio)
print(distance)
```

Can someone please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an entire app for you:

```
import math
from pprint import pprint

class App():
    def __init__(self, rows, txpower):
        self.empty_rows = rows
        self.txpower = txpower

    def get_data_lines_from_file(self, path):
        rv = []
        with open(path) as f:
            lines = f.readlines()

        return lines

    def format_lines(self, lines):
        rv = []
        #columns are separated by whitespace, so remove it and place values in a list
        for i in range(len(lines)):
            lines[i] = ' '.join(lines[i].split()).split()

        #extracting columns names from the top
        column_names = lines[0]

        #removing rows with no data
        lines = lines[self.empty_rows-1:]
        
        for line in lines:
            result = {}
            for i in range(len(line)):
                result.update({
                    column_names[i]: line[i],
                    }
                )
            rv.append(result)
        return rv[1:]


    def calculate_distance(self, rssi):
        ratio =(self.txpower-int(rssi))/40
        distance= math.pow(10,ratio)
        return distance


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App(rows=2, txpower=-40)

    data = app.get_data_lines_from_file('test.txt')
    formatted_data = app.format_lines(data)

    try:

        for i in range(len(formatted_data)):
            rssi = formatted_data[i]['RSSI']
            distance = app.calculate_distance(rssi)
            formatted_data[i].update({'distance':distance})

    except KeyError:
        print("No RSSI value in a file")

    pprint(formatted_data)
```

When you first call the App() object you need to specify how many rows you want to ignore, based on the snippet you provided it should be 2.
Output 'distance' is automatically assigned to a correct entry, so it's easy to pair up with other data.
You can add more columns to the 'test.txt' and it shouldn't disrupt program flow. I made it so that you can use different data sets with similar formats.
Output snippet:

```
[{'MAC': 'AC233FA27B5C',
  'RSSI': '-20',
  'Timestamp': '2021-04-30T14:41:13Z',
  'distance': 0.31622776601683794},
 {'MAC': 'AC233FA27B6A',
  'RSSI': '-23',
  'Timestamp': '2021-04-30T14:41:14Z',
  'distance': 0.3758374042884442},
```

Edit: I've also added the 'txpower' variable to the **init**, to make it more reusable, I don't know what it exactly means, but it's probably a value you might want to adjust later.
Also, you shouldn't need to touch anything inside the App class, the if statement at the bottom is meant for editing.